# how to show the extension in product page?

Tags: extensions

I installed a free extension for Q&A in the following link:
it is supposed to be shown in product details as a form for customers to ask questions

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalog/product/view/id/22878/s/ds-product-faq/

as we know extension location usually is app/code/local or app/code/community , so I found the extension in app/code/local and in app/etc/modules I have the module also in the back-end admin I can see all the configurations so I think I don't have any problem of installation. I have a custom template and I think that I should have a phtml file for the form but I don't know where it is what is your idea? does it exists? if yes how can I find that I searched many terms and I wasn't successful

therefore I created the phtml file and the layout as follow:

app/design/frontend/enterprise/themename/layout/productfaq.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
    </default>
    <productfaq_index_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="productfaq/productfaq" name="web" template="productfaq/productfaq.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </productfaq_index_index>
</layout>
```

app/design/frontend/enterprise/themename/template/productfaq/productfaq.phtml

also here is the structure for the extension:

```
-DS
  -ProductFAQ
     -Block
     -Controllers
     -etc
```

also I have no idea about `productfaq_index_index` I just wrote it because I don't know which element I should use

Comment: Try to copy the extensions layout and template files to your custom theme folder. Are you using Magento EE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of curiosity I just installed this extension myself. I also use a custom theme (Fortis theme by Infortis) for my store.

All you have to do is to copy the following files

app/design/frontend/default/default/**layout/ds_productfaq.xml**
app/design/frontend/default/default/**template/ds_productfaq/faqform.phtml**
app/design/frontend/default/default/**template/ds_productfaq/faqlist.phtml**

to your custom theme directory

app/design/frontend/**MYTHEME**/default/

After that, flush all cache and logout from admin panel and back in. Now the Product FAQ should be visible at the product page.